# config play framework log file location in production

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, logback

I'm using play framework in a project. In order to config the log file related information, I use logback to config it. Here is the sample configuration：

```
<appender name="DEBUGFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/usr/frank/logs/debug.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover with compression -->
        <fileNamePattern>debug-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 1 week worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %message%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

When I run the test like ./activator test or run the application in dev mode ./activator run, I can find the log file get created at the place specified at the file section. But when I run the application in production mode, like ./activator start, the file will not get generated.
Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

In Production mode you have to pass the parameter **logger.file** as shown below.

`-Dlogger.file="/usr/frank/logs/debug.log"`

Comment: `-Dlogger.file` is to "specify a configuration file to be loaded from the file system", not to set where the logs are written: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SettingsLogger#Using--Dlogger.file